# When using .receivedLighting on an arView.environment in RealityKit it does not show lighting

Tags: arkit, realitykit

I noticed that an arView (RealityKit) has the option insert: arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.receivesLighting)

with .receivesLighting description it state: *The .receivesLighting option means that the virtual lights will interact with real world surfaces causing them to shine. The properties of the mesh will be set to a default material.*

This would mean it is possible to relight the real world. It is also indicated in apple's talk: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/609/

However, experimenting with it and having a directional light and/or spotlight added to the AR environment will have no influence on the real-world surfaces. I am using iPad Pro/iphone Pro with LIDAR.

Any idea why not?